# Sound playing twice when character bounces off the ground?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

so pretty much I have set up this function to play a sound when my character hits the ground.

```
 func playSound() {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: "caf")!

    do {
        Sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let Sound = Sound else { return }

        Sound.prepareToPlay()
        Sound.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

It works fine except 1 problem - my hero is falling to the ground and bouncing off the ground which is creating two collisions/playing the sound twice.

Any idea on how I would fix this?

Also is it possible to adjust the volume of a sound in Swift, or does that need to be done externally? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

The func playSound() is called below

```
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.bird && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ground || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.ground && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.bird{


        playSound()


        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "wallPair", using: ({
            (node, error) in

            node.speed = 0
            self.removeAllActions()
        }))

        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "birdFly", using: ({
            (node, error) in

            node.speed = 0
            self.removeAllActions()


        }))


        if died == false{
            died = true
            createButton()
            loseALife()


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to see your code (the func where playSound() gets called), but you could wrap playSound() in an if statement that only succeeds if the translation.y of the fall is greater than a certain number.

As for sound volume, you can set the volume property (Float) of the AVAudioPlayer to a number ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. You could pass it in to your playSound() func:

```
func playSound(with volumeForFall: CGFloat) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: "caf")!

    do {
        Sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let Sound = Sound else { return }

        Sound.volume = volumeForFall

        Sound.prepareToPlay()
        Sound.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And then, call that where you can access the translation.y (the Y distance traversed in the fall) and set the volume accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the right direction! The volume I think has changed due to an updated version of swift.

flap?.volume = 0.1 was added right after the playSound() function is called

I have added the rest of my code in the top where my player dies and falls to the ground. Thanks for your help!